# Two for loops in a comprehensive list

Tags: python, list, loops

```
x = 'green apple'
L = []
for word in x.split():
    for letter in word:
        L.append(letter)
    print(L)
```

The following produces what I want which is a list containing all the letters from the string x. How can I have these two for loops in one line code?

Comment: @kaveh is there a way in which I can produce ['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e'] with one loop?

Comment: Out of curiousity, none of the solutions posted (mine included) take the `print` function into account.  Do you really want to print `['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n']` and then `['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']`?  If so, I don't think you'll too a whole lot better then the loop -- Though the inner loop could be replaced with a `L.extend(word)`.

Comment: Do you know why it prints two lists? I am only interested in the second full one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List comprehensions nest the same way for loops do.  So, the outermost loop comes before the innermost loop.

```
>>> x = 'green apple'
>>> [c for word in x.split() for c in word]
['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

I generally don't use nested list comprehensions because I find that I don't always remember the order, but I know that some people *do* use them so it's useful to be able to remember how they nest.

In this case, I usually prefer to use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split()))
```

Comment: also using star-args `list(itertools.chain(*x.split()))`

Comment: @AyushShanker -- Sure, that'll work, but as a habit, I avoid a bare `chain` with "star-args" because there are circumstances where that makes the iterable less lazy -- And the whole point of itertools is to do _more_ lazy evaluation :-).  In this case it doesn't make much difference though (aside from building a possibly bad habit).

Answer (score 5):

```
x = 'green apple'
print [i for i in x if i !=" "]
```

You can directly do this.

Output:`['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']`

or

```
import re
x = 'green apple'
print re.findall("\S",x)
```

Comment: If your input really is as simple as `'green apple'`, this is the solution that I'd go with. . .

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> list(x.replace(' ',''))
# ['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

works well for lines too

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with leaving the space, you can simply use the list function:

```
x = 'green apple'
print list(x)
```

To omit the space:

```
x = 'green apple'
print [letter for letter in x if not letter == ' ']
```

Comment: strings are iterable so there's no need for `list(x)` -- `x` would suffice by itself.  Also, I doubt that too many people like the `_` in the list comprehension.  It just feels a bit odd. . .

Comment: @mgilson noted & revised :)

Comment: Ahh, and PEP8 advises against using `l` as a variable name (apparently it looks too much like `1` in some fonts) ;-).

Comment: Yes it does. I dislike "l" as a variable name for that reason, let's go with a fully explicit name like `letter`, instead.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop at all. You can accomplish the same by doing this:

```
>>> x = "green apple"
>>> list(x)
['g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n', ' ', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

Comment: Not quite -- you'll have an extra space (which others have already posted solutions that filter it out).

Comment: This does not take care of the space.